# get image width during image upload ajax php

Tags: php, ajax, file, getimagesize

I am using ajax file upload and i have couple of validation work on it but i want determine width of image during upload and show error message if low width image but i don't get any thing in $_FILES variable so Here it works with $_GET but using that i cant determine width using getimagesize function.how ever i can determine file size using $_SERVER['content_length'].I tried function using getresolution();

it uses fileupload js librarary

https://github.com/Valums-File-Uploader/file-uploader

Here is code of ajax upload php file.Please help me.

```
   class qqUploadedFileXhr {
    /**
     * Save the file to the specified path
     * @return boolean TRUE on success
     */
    function save($path) {    
        $input = fopen("php://input", "r");
        $temp = tmpfile();
        $realSize = stream_copy_to_stream($input, $temp);
        fclose($input);

        if ($realSize != $this->getSize()){            
            return false;
        }

        $target = fopen($path, "w");        
        fseek($temp, 0, SEEK_SET);
        stream_copy_to_stream($temp, $target);
        fclose($target);

        return true;
    }
    function getresolution(){
        $size_res=getimagesize($_GET['qqfile']);

         return $size_res[0];
        // return implode("<br>",$_SERVER);

    }
    function getName() {
        return $_GET['qqfile'];
    }
    function getSize() {
        if (isset($_SERVER["CONTENT_LENGTH"])){
            return (int)$_SERVER["CONTENT_LENGTH"];            
        } else {
            throw new Exception('Getting content length is not supported.');
        }      
    }   
}

/**
 * Handle file uploads via regular form post (uses the $_FILES array)
 */
class qqUploadedFileForm {  
    /**
     * Save the file to the specified path
     * @return boolean TRUE on success
     */ 
    function save($path) {
        if(!move_uploaded_file($_FILES['qqfile']['tmp_name'], $path)){
            return false;
        }

        return true;
    }
    function mms(){
         return $_FILES['qqfile']['tmp_name'];
    }
    function getName() {
        //return $_FILES['qqfile']['name'];
    }
    function getSize() {
        return $_FILES['qqfile']['size'];
    }
}

class qqFileUploader {
    private $allowedExtensions = array();
    private $sizeLimit = 10485760;
    private $file;

    function __construct(array $allowedExtensions = array(), $sizeLimit = 10485760){        
        $allowedExtensions = array_map("strtolower", $allowedExtensions);

        $this->allowedExtensions = $allowedExtensions;        
        $this->sizeLimit = $sizeLimit;

        $this->checkServerSettings();       

        if (isset($_GET['qqfile'])) {
            $this->file = new qqUploadedFileXhr();
        } elseif (isset($_FILES['qqfile'])) {
            $this->file = new qqUploadedFileForm();
        } else {
            $this->file = false; 
        }
    }

    private function checkServerSettings(){        
        $postSize = $this->toBytes(ini_get('post_max_size'));
        $uploadSize = $this->toBytes(ini_get('upload_max_filesize'));        

        if ($postSize < $this->sizeLimit || $uploadSize < $this->sizeLimit){
            $size = max(1, $this->sizeLimit / 1024 / 1024) . 'M';             
            die("{'error':'increase post_max_size and upload_max_filesize to $size'}");    
        }        
    }

    private function toBytes($str){
        $val = trim($str);
        $last = strtolower($str[strlen($str)-1]);
        switch($last) {
            case 'g': $val *= 1024;
            case 'm': $val *= 1024;
            case 'k': $val *= 1024;        
        }
        return $val;
    }

    /**
     * Returns array('success'=>true) or array('error'=>'error message')
     */
    function handleUpload($uploadDirectory, $replaceOldFile = FALSE){

        if (!is_writable($uploadDirectory)){
            return array('error' => $uploadDirectory);
        }

        if (!$this->file){
            return array('error' => 'No files were uploaded.');
        }

        $size = $this->file->getSize();

        if ($size == 0) {
            return array('error' => 'File is empty');
        }

        if ($size < $this->sizeLimit) {
            return array('error' => $this->file->getresolution());
        }

        $pathinfo   = pathinfo($this->file->getName());
        if( ! isset($pathinfo['filename'])){
            $pathinfo['filename'] = $pathinfo['basename'];
        }        
        $old_name   = $pathinfo['filename'] . '.' . $pathinfo['extension'];
        $filename   = md5($pathinfo['filename'].uniqid('mysecretAHSH',mt_rand()));

        $ext        = $pathinfo['extension'];

        if($this->allowedExtensions && !in_array(strtolower($ext), $this->allowedExtensions)){
            $these = implode(', ', $this->allowedExtensions);
            return array('error' => 'File has an invalid extension, it should be one of '. $these . '.');
        }

        if(!$replaceOldFile){
            /// don't overwrite previous files that were uploaded
            while (file_exists($uploadDirectory . $filename . '.' . $ext)) {
                $filename =  md5($filename . rand(10, 99));
            }
        }

        if ($this->file->save($uploadDirectory . $filename . '.' . $ext)){
             return array('success'=>true,'size'=>$size,'file_on_disk_name'=>$filename. '.' . $ext,'file_name'=>$old_name);         
        } else {
            return array('error'=> 'Could not save uploaded file.' .
                'The upload was cancelled, or server error encountered');
        }

    }    
}

/**
 * 
 * @author Andrei
 *
 */
class Ajax_file_upload {
    private $allowedExtensions = array();
    private $sizeLimit = 10485760;
    private $file;

    function __construct(array $allowedExtensions = array(), $sizeLimit = 10485760){        
        $allowedExtensions = array_map("strtolower", $allowedExtensions);

        $this->allowedExtensions = $allowedExtensions;        
        $this->sizeLimit = $sizeLimit;

        $this->checkServerSettings();       

        if (isset($_GET['qqfile'])) {
            $this->file = new qqUploadedFileXhr();
        } else {
            $this->file = false; 
        }
    }

    private function checkServerSettings(){        
        $postSize = $this->toBytes(ini_get('post_max_size'));
        $uploadSize = $this->toBytes(ini_get('upload_max_filesize'));        

        if ($postSize < $this->sizeLimit || $uploadSize < $this->sizeLimit){
            $size = max(1, $this->sizeLimit / 1024 / 1024) . 'M';             
            die("{'error':'increase post_max_size and upload_max_filesize to $size'}");    
        }        
    }

    private function toBytes($str){
        $val = trim($str);
        $last = strtolower($str[strlen($str)-1]);
        switch($last) {
            case 'g': $val *= 1024;
            case 'm': $val *= 1024;
            case 'k': $val *= 1024;        
        }
        return $val;
    }

    /**
     * Returns array('success'=>true) or array('error'=>'error message')
     */
    function handleUpload($uploadDirectory, $replaceOldFile = FALSE){
        if (!is_writable($uploadDirectory)){
            return array('error' => "Server error. Upload directory isn't writable.");
        }

        if (!$this->file){
            return array('error' => 'No files were uploaded.');
        }

        $size = $this->file->getSize();

        if ($size == 0) {
            return array('error' => 'File is empty');
        }

        if ($size > $this->sizeLimit) {
            return array('error' => 'File is too large');
        }

        $pathinfo   = pathinfo($this->file->getName());
        if( ! isset($pathinfo['filename'])){
            $pathinfo['filename'] = $pathinfo['basename'];
        }        
        $old_name   = $pathinfo['filename'] . '.' . $pathinfo['extension'];        
        $filename   = md5($pathinfo['filename'].uniqid('mysecretAHSH',mt_rand()));
        $ext        = $pathinfo['extension'];

        if($this->allowedExtensions && !in_array(strtolower($ext), $this->allowedExtensions)){
            $these = implode(', ', $this->allowedExtensions);
            return array('error' => 'File has an invalid extension, it should be one of '. $these . '.');
        }

        if(!$replaceOldFile){
            /// don't overwrite previous files that were uploaded
            while (file_exists($uploadDirectory . $filename . '.' . $ext)) {
                $filename = md5($filename . rand(10, 99));
            }
        }

        if ($this->file->save($uploadDirectory . $filename . '.' . $ext)){
             return array('success'=>true,'size'=>$size,'file_on_disk_name'=>$filename. '.' . $ext,'file_name'=>$old_name);         
        } else {
            return array('error'=> 'Could not save uploaded file.' .
                'The upload was cancelled, or server error encountered');
        }

    }    
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could listen for when the file is selected client side and get the width using the FileReader API. I have done a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/t9mwfuoo/2/

```
$('.upload').on('change', function(e) {

    var file = e.target.files[0];

    var fr  = new FileReader(); 

    fr.readAsDataURL(file);

    fr.onload = function(frEvent) {

        var tmpImage = new Image();
        tmpImage.src = frEvent.target.result;

        tmpImage.onload = function() {

            if (tmpImage.width <= 180) {

                alert('Image width is equal to or less than 180 pixels');

            } else {

                alert('Image width is larger than 180 pixels');

            }

        }
    }

});
```

Comment: hi thats great,but when i write  if(tmpImage.width == 180 )  {
    
    alert ('Image size is less than 388 Upload big'); it works but when i write tmpImage.width < =180 it does not go inside loop

Comment: If you want to use a conditional statement then I have updated my fiddle to give you an example: http://jsfiddle.net/t9mwfuoo/2/

Comment: hi one more question.i am using this with jquery validate,where do i put it to validate

Answer (score 0):

This link will help you.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagesx.php

the function imagesx returns the width of an image.

```
<?php

echo imagesx($img); // returns the width

?>
```

For your code you have to use

```
<?php

    $file_width = imagesx($_FILES['qqfile']);

?>
```

I hope this will help you.

Comment: hello i tried $size_res=imagesx($_GET['qqfile']); but it returns nothing.What should i do?

Comment: code edited You have to use the File as it is not the get parameter with the Path